# Weight painting mode right click action differs from time to time

Tags: weight-painting

Anyone know why sometimes when you weight paint a rigged model, right click selects the bone and allows you to rotate it, while other times, it kicks you out to object mode even if you right click the exact same spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the armature is in pose mode, and you select the skinned object, it will let you pose the armature if you select any bone. On the other hand, if the armature is in object mode it will take you back to object mode.

Actually, this is standard for all objects in that selection by right-clicking in the viewport will put the viewport in whatever mode that object was last in.

[image]

Note that selecting another object in edit mode or particle edit mode will not work.

Comment: Thank you! That was super unintuitive. I would never have figured out that connection. God damnit, Blender.